# spatial join field mapping Arcpy, change merge rule

Tags: arcpy, merge, spatial-join, field-mapping

I have a line feature class which represents a stream network. At a confluence of two river segments, I'm joining the stream segments to the point of intersection via spatial join (one to one join). I would like to keep only the attribute of the field "level_St" (type: SHORT), all other attributes are not relevant for me. For the Join of the "level_St" attribute, I would like to specify a merge rule keeping only the maximum value.

Comment: Join 1:M and summarise by node ID, stats=max

Comment: Can you do it manually (no ArcPy) yet? If so, then just use the Geoprocessing | Results window to Copy As Python Snippet and paste into a script.  That way most of your code is already written and you should post some code.  If you do not yet know how to do this manually then I think you should make this an ArcGIS for Desktop geoprocessing tools question rather an ArcPy one.